# How to get Visio Guide line direction

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to set up some code that will have align a sub-shape in a group to a guide line on drop, but I only want to align to horizontal guides, not vertical.  As yet I have not found a good way to programmatically determine what direction a guide is, only how to add guides.

So is there some property I've not found that will tell me the direction of the line?  Even the guide's shapesheet doesn't seem to have anything to tell me this.

Comment: I know I can use the Path.Points method to get the 'start' and 'end' points of the line, but I'm wondering if there's a concrete way to tell what type of guide it is (point, horiz line, vert line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Angle cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768387%28v=office.15%29.aspx).  0 or 180 is horizontal and 90 or 270 is vertical.

A guide is just a Shape with an InfiniteLine geometry row type and a point guide has no geometry at all.